# Uneven distribution of tasks among the spark executors

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.1.1

I am using spark-streaming 2.2.1 on production and in this application i read the data from [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq) and do the further processing and finally save it in the cassandra. So, i am facing this strange issue where number of tasks are not evenly distributed amongst executors on one of the nodes. I restarted the streaming but still issue persist.[image]

As you can see on `10.10.4.72` i have 2 executors. The one running on **41893** port has completed approx. double the number of tasks on rest of the nodes (`10.10.3.73` and `10.10.3.72`). where as executor running on **33451** port on `10.10.4.72` has completed only 18 tasks. And this issue persist even if i restart my spark-streaming.

**Edit question**
After 12 hours still as you can see in the below image the same executor has not processed not even a single task in this duration.

[image]

Comment: `further processing` has filters? Data Locality could be the reason.

Comment: were you able to find the issue?